# Singleton Postgres Database Client Staying Connected

Tags: node.js, singleton

I have the following Singleton class that represents my database:

```js
const { Client } = require('pg');
require('dotenv').config();

class DatabaseSingleton {
    constructor() {
        if (!DatabaseSingleton.instance) {
            const clientOptions = {
                user: process.env.DatabaseUsername,
                host: process.env.DatabaseHost,
                database: process.env.DatabaseName,
                password: process.env.DatabasePassword,
                port: process.env.DatabasePort
            };
            this.client = new Client(clientOptions);

            DatabaseSingleton.instance = this;
        }

        return DatabaseSingleton.instance;
    }
}

module.exports = new DatabaseSingleton();
```

I then have the following code that uses the Singleton class to connect to the database, optionally log the error, and then end the connection:

```js
try {
    await database.client.connect();
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM public.user WHERE username = $1;';
    const queryParams = [username];
    const result = await database.client.query(query, queryParams);

    // test purposes only, I'm not actually going to hardcode 'admin'
    const adminPasswordHash = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.hash('admin', saltRounds, function(bcryptError, bcryptResult) {
            if (bcryptError) {
                reject(bcryptError);
            }
            resolve(bcryptResult);
        });
    });
    
    const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password || '', adminPasswordHash || '');
    if (result.values?.length || !passwordMatch) {
        throw new Error('Invalid username and/or password.');
    }
    return true;
} catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
} finally {
    await database.client.end();
}
```

The issue is if I walkthrough the following workflow:

1. Perform a successful login
2. Logout
3. Perform an invalid login

I get the following error when I go to do step 3 on the `await database.client.connect();` portion of my code:

> Error:  Error: Client has already been connected. You cannot reuse a client.

I thought that the code in my `finally` would end that connection, what am I missing?

**Update**

I think this may have something to do with how I'm setting up the Singleton class because if I move the creation of a new client to the function it works fine.

Comment: Just consider using the pool client